# Вопрос по Visual Studio C#. Как в одном решении делать несколько "проектов"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, проекты

В методичке задание сделать АТД "Дек". Под это задание выделяется несколько лабораторных работ.
Во второй лабе надо сделать сам дек. К нему сделать тесты.
В третьей лабе в этом деке реализовать интерфейсы IEnumerable и IClonable. К новым методам сделать тесты
и т.д.

У меня в Visual Studio в решении есть консольное приложение с классом дека и библиотека классов с тестами к классу дек. (Lab2 и Lab2_Test на скрине).
Я хочу 3 лабу сделать в этом же решении, НО доделав сам дек уже в другом консольном приложении и тесты к классу.
Т.е. 
Заходишь в проект Lab2 и там видишь первоначальный класс дек и класс Program, в котором используется класс дек.
Заходишь в  Lab_Test, а там тесты к классу дек из проекта Lab2.
Заходишь в Lab3 а там тот же самый дек, только с реализованными интерфейсами.
Заходишь в Lab3_Test, а там те же самые тесты + тесты для методов, реализующих наследуемые интерфейсыю

Я так и сделал, НО:
В обозревателе тестов количество тестов удвоилось. Там тесты из Lab2_Test и из Lab3_Test.
Я хочу, чтобы в обозревателе тестов выполнялись тесты того проекта, который выделен (в обозревателе решений).
Когда я компилирую, то запускается консольное приложение из Lab2.
Я хочу, чтобы компилировался тот проект, который выделен (в обозревателе решений).

**Такое в Visual Studio вообще можно сделать (без git)? Если можно, то как?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну сделайте две группы тестов, и запускайте нужную. Делов-то!

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы в тестах 3 лабы были тесты из второй лабы (соответственно названия у них будут идентичны) и тесты, которые я допишу. И эти тесты тестировали класс в Lab3.

Я так и сделал.

НО при запуске тестов запускаются и отображаются тесты из Lab2_Test и Lab3_Test. Это забивает панель. Я хочу видеть тесты только из 3 лабы.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно *скомпилировать* только один проект, то щёлкаете на нём правой кнопкой мыши в Обозревателе решений, выбираете в контекстном меню пункт Build / Построить.

Если нужно *запустить* какой-то конкретный проект, аналогично щёлкаете на нём правой кнопкой мыши, выбираете в контекстном меню пункт Set as StartUp Project / Сделать проект стартовым. После чего при нажатии (Ctrl+)F5 будет запускаться именно он.

Тесты можно запускать произвольно любые. Просто выделяете нужные и всё.